# Collision versus force: is there a difference?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, collision

In classical physics, it is known that a force perpendicular to the velocity of a body does no work and cannot change the magnitude of the velocity but only the direction. Nevertheless also in classical physics it is known that when a body hits a perpendicular moving body it increases its velocity.
Isn't hitting a body the same as applying a force? Seems like a contradiction.

Comment: As soon as the force is applied it's no longer perpendicular to the motion. Or do you mean it's perpendicular the entire time even as the trajectory changes direction?

Comment: Hitting is applied in to a body in an instant. So the force applied by hitting is perpendicular  in the instant of the hitting. The second body should NOT change velocity but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a force is only going to keep the velocity magnitude of the target body constant, if the transferred momentum is infinitely small. This is actually a slightly convoluted way of saying: the force that is perpendicular to the body's velocity is generally going to keep the velocity magnitude constant only in a single moment. You can't generally assume that the force is also staying perpendicular "one moment later" (because at least the direction of velocity itself has already changed), and therefore, you can't assume that the velocity magnitude is staying constant over a prolonged duration. An important case where this assumption is actually true, however, is of course the Lorentz force on a charged particle in the magnetic field.

What happens during a perpendicular impact is that a finite amount of momentum is transferred to the target body, which violates the introductory condition. Actually any impact has a finite duration, during which initially perpendicular force and velocity can change to non-perpendicular:
$$\Delta \vec p = \int \vec F dt$$
Just as an example: if the force $\vec F$ is assumed to be constant (which will usually **not** be the case during an impact, but it is easier to calculate), then (P=mechanical power)
$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(\vec F\cdot \vec v)=\vec F\cdot\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=\frac{1}{m}\vec F^2>0$$
Thus, even if initially $P=\vec F\cdot v=0$ due to perpendicularity, in the next moment will be $P>0$ (because velocity magnitude of the target body increases).

Comment: Hi Oliver. Thank you very much for your considerations. You somehow split the force in two parts: one at moment t turning only the velocity direction (nevertheless how big v and F are!!!) and a second part which accelerates parallel after t+dt. But the II Newtons law strictly insists that F immediately accelerates in F direction. I can't understand what is the "transferred momentum is infinitely small"? We know that there is no such thing as infinitely small transfer (QM proves that E is quantized and E and p arrive in finite parcels to a body (or particle) EVER. I feel inconsistancy in CP.

Comment: @Mercury: you asked about classical physics, so no need to bring quantum mechanics into play. And in classical physics there *IS* infintely small momentum transfer. This is the essence of $\vec F=d\vec p/dt$. Force means infinitely small momentum change in an infinitely short duration, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Ok I agree that in CP the dp is inf. small. (and that the hit is of finite duration). But F makes a body to move in its direction immediately. E.g dp is always in direction of F. So the vector sum v+dv should not be equal to v but bigger even when dv is inf. small - As it is when the force is parallel to v - one also has v+dv and gets a bigger velocity.